# How to determine for what value of P does A have a higher probability than B

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is:
"A planes engine has the chance of P to function properly,
A majority of the engines must function in order to fly the plane.
Plane A has 5 engines and plane B has 3 engines, what values of P are prefferable for plane A?"

I managed using wolfram to come to the conclusion that P > 0.39171 would be better for A, but I dont know the proper way to get this answer, 
How would you find P?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we need at least 3 of $A$s engines to be running and at least 2 of $B$s engines. So for fixed $P$ we want to find out the probability of these happening, and compare them.

So now the question becomes, what is the probability? Well if we label $A$s engines $a,b,c,d,e$ then we want at least 3 of these to run, so we could have $\{a,b,c\}$, $\{a,b,d\}$, $\{a,b,e\}$... but counting these separately is a bother. The quick way is to use the binomial distribution. So we have 
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{at least 3 engines run})=\binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2+\binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p)^1+\binom{5}{5}p^5(1-p)^0
$$

Now you do the same thing for plane $B$ and find for which choice of $p$ is the $A$ probability bigger than the $B$ probability.

Another helpful insight may be to re-write the problem. e.g. say you have a biased coin, what range of biases would mean that it is more likely that you throw at least 3 heads out of 5 than throwing 2 heads out of 3.

Comment: Thanks James, I had actually arrived at this stage in my calculations, but this is where I encountered the problem of determining for which values of P plane A has better chance of working. I have 10p^5-15p^4+10p^3 chance for plane A and 3p^2-2p^3 chance for plane B, I cant figure out how to calculate P from here. (How do I make mathematical expressions appear properly?)